# Crear un campo para la inserción de datos en Power BI

Tags: powerbi

Mi idea es la creación de un cuadro de mandos en power BI, que en base a un valor que se introduzca en el informe recalcule ese dato. Pero no veo forma de crear ese cuadro de texto en el que pueda insertar ese valor.

Gracias de antemano!

Comment: Tienes la reputación necesaria para saber que si no agregas el código que has intentado, tu pregunta puede terminar cerrada y con calificaciones negativas.

Comment: pero no hay código de power BI, es la creación de un cuadro de texto que no sé si quiera si se puede crear

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Puedes crear una tabla manual e introducir los datos que tu quieras, poner un filtro en el informe que haga referencia a ese valor, luego crear una fórmula que tenga en cuenta el valor.

También lo puedes automatizar con una [opción pensada](http://blog.blauservices.com/?p=1685) para eso con la funcionalidad denominada [What-if](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/power-bi/desktop-what-if).

Lo que pretende esta funcionalidad es lo que mencionaba en el primer párrafo. Disponer de una variable que influya en una fórmula DAX, de manera que puedas tener un informe dinámico en función del filtro aplicado que cambia el valor del cálculo.